# How to include .iuml path to generate PlantUML diagram in Doxygen

Tags: documentation, uml, doxygen, class-diagram, plantuml

I'm working on the documentation of a component using [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) and I want to include `UML`diagrams in between the text.

I know how to do most of it, as I simply need to copy the `.tuml` source into my `.dox` file and run `doxygen`. However, one of my diagrams is a class diagram that includes other `.iuml` files, like explained in the PlantUML [site](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/preprocessing.html).

So, basically, I do:

```
@mainpage main_page MyDoxygen
\
...
\
@startuml
\
!include iuml_files/Class01.iuml
!include iuml_files/Class02.iuml
\
MainClass <|-- Class01
MainClass <|-- Class02
\
@enduml
```

Long story short, I don't know how to make Doxygen understand it must look for the `.iuml` files in the directory (relative path) I'm giving as argument to the include directive.

If I wasn't clear enough as to what I need, please let me know and I will try make it clearer.

Can I please get some help?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem (I own the Word Add-in for plantuml)

You can specify the java property "plantuml.include.path" in the command line :
java -Dplantuml.include.path="c:/mydir" -jar plantuml.jar atest1.txt
(see http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/preprocessing.html)

I expect it'll work when you modify the batch file for calling Plantuml
http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/doxygen.html

I had a similar request for my Word Addin for Plantuml and here it worked.

Comment: Hi @Adriaan !
I believe it is simpler than that.
A few minutes after I posted this question, I found I had a dumb mistake: the files I needed weren't exactly in that path I was describing. Placing them in the correct directory made everything work as expected.

I had already formulated an answer asking people to simply disregard my question, as I had already found the solution, but I found out I could only post an answer to my own question 6 hours later...and it turns out I forgot.

Noob user here. Thanks for trying to help!

P.S.: Can't even "vote up" your reply. I don't have 15 rep yet.

Answer (score 0):

**The Real Answer**

Use the `PLANTUML_INCLUDE_PATH  = ./someRelativeDir` configuration, visible in the Doxygen wizard's DOT panel.

The include path is relative to your Doxygen config, ie the starting directory from which the doxygen config is taken.

**A Red Herring**

I'm leaving the rest of this answer here in case anyone found it previously.

I **wrongly reported a bug** because I needed new reading glasses and didn't notice a stray character in my path.

This was resolved as **not** a [Doxygen bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=795962)

For any interested parties, this is what I saw.

```
Running PlantUML on generated file /Users/andydent/dev/touchgramdesign/doxygeneratedTG4IM/html/inline_umlgraph_1.pu
Preprocessor Error: Cannot include /Users/andydent/dev/touchgramdesign/doxygeneratedTG4IM/html/handDrawnStyle.iuml
Error line 2 in file: /Users/andydent/dev/touchgramdesign/doxygeneratedTG4IM/html/inline_umlgraph_1.pu
Some diagram description contains errors
error: Problems running PlantUML. Verify that the command 'java -jar "/Library/Java/Extensions/plantuml.jar" -h' works from the command line. Exit code: 1
```

This is using the configuration setting

`PLANTUML_INCLUDE_PATH  = ./iumltToCopy`

Sharper eyes than mine (at the time) noticed the extra character in the path `iuml` **t** `ToCopy`